# cpp message generation failure?

Tags: ros, catkin, raspberrypi, message-generation, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to finish setting up my p2os_driver package that I've converted to groovy & catkin and have hit another speedbump.

```
cd catkin_ws/src
wstool set p2os_driver --git https://github.com/dawonn/ros-p2os-driver
wstool update
cd catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

This process works fine on my ubuntu 12.04 machine but not on my raspberry pi.
On my rpi I get:

```
In file included from /home/dereck/cws/src/p2os_driver/src/p2osnode.cc:31:0:
/home/dereck/cws/src/p2os_driver/include/p2os.h:40:26: fatal error: BatteryState.h: No such file or directory
```

and there are no messages in the catkin_ws/devel/include/p2os_driver directory on the rasPi, but they are there on the ubuntu machine.

In other words,
What could cause CPP message headers not to be generated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56489/cpp-message-generation-failure?/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make will automatically build all your CMake target in parallel. In your case you have to tell CMake that it must generate C++ code for the messages (BatteryState.h) before compiling p2osnode.cpp.

You do that by adding a dependency form the executable you are building to the gencpp target which generates the messages headers. Adding something like the following line to your CMakeLists.txt:

`add_dependencies(<target_name_of_your_executable_or_library> <msg_pkg_name_containing_the_battery_state>_genpp)`

See https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/groovy-devel/clients/roscpp/CMakeLists.txt#L118 for an example

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2